# Acrobat DRAG and Drop a button

Tags: drag-and-drop, acrobat

What I'm trying to do is have a base map graphic with the ability to drag icon (button) graphics around on it in a PDF. I inquired in the Adobe Acrobat forum and got a reply that gave me a couple steps on how it could be done...but of course, absolutely now guidance on how to actually do it.

The steps included having a button graphic the size of the entire map...place my icons (buttons) and use the mouseX and mouseY to determine if the icon is under the cursor...and if so, use the setInterval to DRAG it.

The steps sound simple but I'm getting nowhere trying to figure it out...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You really don't want to do that. While the solution that was *outlined* for you on the forum will work to allow a user to move graphics around on a PDF page, I doubt you'll find the experience to be acceptable. Acrobat JavaScript just wasn't designed to do that kind of thing. There will be a whole lot of flickering and if you have maps that are made of vectors rather than just an image, there'll be A WHOLE LOT OF FLICKERING. You really, really, want to rethink your solution.

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate the caution and the map will be an image not vector...but can you help me get this to work?

Comment: Putting something like this together is non-trivial and will ultimately be unsatisfying to you; trust me on this. I program PDF files for a living and I wouldn't even take this on as a consulting engagement. Rethink your solution.

Comment: Really, I understand your point of view, but it's something I have to do. Any help would be appreciated but I guess you have bowed out gracefully. Thanks for replying.

Comment: You probably don't actually need to do what you describe, there are *always* alternatives. Do you just need to move icons around or do they *have* to be buttons? Do you need the icons to do stuff after being placed? How much control do you have over the install? Are the users using Acrobat or Reader? If you want to take this offline, my name is very Google friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your users have a higher tolerance for flickering than joelgeraci's users. Furthermore advances in PDF readers (such as Adobe Acrobat) may have reduced the "flickering". To give your users the opportunity to make this evaluation for themselves please check out the [PDF document at academia.edu](https://www.academia.edu/44958550/A_Prototype_for_Testing_Edwards_Users_Experience) that I recently uploaded -- it includes a map with three icons that can be dragged around.